# Adding integers from a file to NSarray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

in my application I'm going to need to convert a path to its point representation. So I'm going to have tons of points. I need to add all those integers to an NSArray. I'll then iterate through that array and use those points to place my objects on the screen. How can I add those points (probably X and Y parts seperately) to an NSArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way to add points in an array is

> ```
> [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]
> ```

where point is of type CGPoint.
while fetching you can fetch the CGPoint as

> ```
> CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
> where value is [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]
> ```

Comment: Is this an `NSBezierPath`?  Could you enumerate the points, e.g. `elementCount`, `elementAtIndex:associatedPoints:` and box the points as described above in the enumeration loop?

Answer (score 0):

you can add into NSArray using `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:intNumber]`

Comment: That's the way I would go if there were only a few points. But there going to be 500-600 points in average.

Comment: NSMutableArray is preferred. create object, then you can use [arr addObject:obj]; to add object.